# cannot access parent:: when current class scope has no parent

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can solve this problem please ?
It give me problem error

cannot access parent:: when current class scope has no parent

I don't know what i can do please help

```
class MY_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->driver("cache", ["adapter" => "apc", "backup" => "file", "key_prefix" => "vie_"]);
        $this->data = [];
        $this->data["settings"] = $this->m_core->getSettings();
        $this->config->load("config", true);
        if (md5("" . get_domain_host(base_url())) != $this->config->item(base64_decode("="), "config")) {
            exit(base64_decode(""));
        }
        $this->data["csrf_name"] = $this->security->get_csrf_token_name();
        $this->data["csrf_hash"] = $this->security->get_csrf_hash();
    }
}
```

Comment: you can't access `parent::...` because there is no parent class, so stop trying to access the parent which does not exist

Comment: Please can u edit this code for me

Comment: don't have any code that is trying to access `parent::...` or have this class extend from another class

Comment: Yes i have
```class Page extends MY_Controller
{

 public function index()
 {
  $this->data['all_pages'] = $this->m_page->get_all_pages();
  $this->data['page'] = 'All Pages';
  $this->load->view('user_template/pages', $this->data);
 }

 public function proof()
 {
  $this->data['page'] = 'Payment Proofs';
  $this->db->order_by('id', "desc")->limit(20);
  $this->data['proofs'] = $this->db->get('withdraw_history')->result_array();
  $this->load->view('user_template/proof', $this->data);
 }

Comment: please don't add edits in the comment section, but in your original post, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If your class is extending another class, you will be able to use the parent's class constructor.

Example,

```php
class DummyParent {
  public function __construct() {
    // do something with the class instance ...
  }
}

class DummyChild extends DummyParent {
  public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
  }
}
```

In your case, your `MY_Controller` is not extending any class. It is pointless to call the `parent::__construct()` because it has no parent class at all. You should either:

1. modify `MY_Controller` to extend another class that has a useful constructor; or
2. simply remove the `parent::__construct()` line in the `MY_Controller` class.